# call the function in function of custom library in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, static-libraries, encapsulation

I have a library which looks like the following

```
(function (bindDropdownAndSetValue) {
    function allFunction() {
        function bindDropDownValue(response, dropdownObject) {
            $.each(response, function (i, e) {
                $('#' + dropdownObject.id).append('<option value=' + e[dropdownObject.value] + '>' + e[dropdownObject.text] + '</option>');
            });
        }

        function dropdownValues(id, value, text) {
            this.id = id;
            this.value = value;
            this.text = text;
        }
    }
    bindDropdownAndSetValue.allFunction = allFunction;
} (bindDropdownAndSetValue));
```

in the above example when I call `bindDropdownAndSetValue.allFunction`  I want to excess the functions inside allFunction but it didn't appear to work

and when I changed the library to like the following

```
(function (bindDropdownAndSetValue) {
    function bindDropDownValue(response, dropdownObject) {
        $.each(response, function (i, e) {
            $('#' + dropdownObject.id).append('<option value=' + e[dropdownObject.value] + '>' + e[dropdownObject.text] + '</option>');
        });
    }

    function dropdownValues(id, value, text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.text = text;
    }
    bindDropdownAndSetValue.bindDropDownValue = bindDropDownValue;
    bindDropdownAndSetValue.dropdownValues = dropdownValues;
} (bindDropdownAndSetValue));
```

this works fine, but the problem here is that I need to right extra line of code, to assign `function` one by one to `bindDropdownAndSetValue`.

Is there any other better way to right this code?

Comment: just `return { bindDropDownValue,  dropdownValues};`

Comment: Your code style differs from the mainstream style. I suggest you look into the oop style before es6 and consider es6 class style too.

Comment: @ShaileshRathod tried but didn't work

Comment: @obfish thank you for your suggestion, I will consider what you said but now I am working on live project and this thing is irritating me, so can I get any idea on this?

Comment: Maybe `Object.assign(bindDropdownAndSetValue, {bindDropDownValue, dropdownValues})` if you have to stick to this style.

Comment: thanks a lot, if you have any suggestions for better styles you can give me

Comment: What is `allFunction` supposed to be? It doesn't do anything but define two local functios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep it short and simple:

```
bindDropdownAndSetValue.bindDropDownValue = function(response, dropdownObject) {
    $.each(response, function (i, e) {
        $('#' + dropdownObject.id).append('<option value=' + e[dropdownObject.value] + '>' + e[dropdownObject.text] + '</option>');
    });
};
bindDropdownAndSetValue.dropdownValues = function(id, value, text) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value = value;
    this.text = text;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (function (bindDropdownAndSetValue) {
    function bindDropDownValue(response, dropdownObject) {
        $.each(response, function (i, e) {
            $('#' + dropdownObject.id).append('<option value=' + e[dropdownObject.value] + '>' + e[dropdownObject.text] + '</option>');
        });
    }

    function dropdownValues(id, value, text) {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
        this.text = text;
    }
    Object.assign(bindDropdownAndSetValue, {bindDropDownValue, dropdownValues });
} (bindDropdownAndSetValue));
```

Comment: oh yup, you don't even need to reassign it to `bindDropdownAndSetValue `